# Изменение слоя в jCanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Рисую, используя *jCanvas*. Создала текст, который меняет цвет при наведении мыши. Но я использую `setLayer`, то есть, получается, создаю новый слой. Поэтому новая надпись исчезает при наведении мыши. Непонятно только почему на весь слой, а не только на первый текст.

Мне нужно, чтобы первый текст по-прежнему менял цвет при наведении мыши, но все остальное оставалось неизменным.

[Демо](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=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).

```
$('canvas').drawText({
    fillStyle: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    x: 150, y: 100,
    fontSize: 48,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    text: 'Hello',
    layer: true,
    mouseover: function(layer) {
        $(this).setLayer(layer, {
            fillStyle:'red',
        })
        .drawLayers();
    },
    mouseout: function(layer) {
        $(this).setLayer(layer, {
            fillStyle:'green'
        })
        .drawLayers();
    },
 });

$('canvas').drawText({
    x: 150, y: 300,
    fillStyle: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 34,
    text: 'Hello'
})
```

Comment: Странное дело в этом демо. Если убрать `mouseover` и `mouseout`, то при наведении и убирании мыши с `canvas` нижний текст исчезает.Это вообще нормально? Видимо, срабатывает `drawLayers()`, потому что если добавить в конце кода `$('canvas').drawLayers();`, то результат будет такой же: нижний текст исчезает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что у второго текста не установлено свойство `layer: true`. Как результат - его нет в списке слоёв, и при вызове `.drawLayers();` он перестаёт быть видимым.

Исправленный код:

```
var $canvas = $('canvas');
$canvas.drawText({
    fillStyle: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    x: 150, y: 100,
    fontSize: 48,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
    text: 'Hello',
    layer: true,
    mouseover: function(layer) {
        $(this).setLayer(layer, {
            fillStyle: 'red'
        }).drawLayers();
    },
    mouseout: function(layer) {
        $(this).setLayer(layer, {
            fillStyle: 'green'
        }).drawLayers();
    }
});
$canvas.drawText({
    x: 150, y: 300,
    fillStyle: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 34,
    text: 'Hello',
    layer: true
});
```

[Полный пример в jCanvas Sandbox](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=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).